# JQuery 'Change' event handler for asp.net radiobuttonlist not triggering event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, event-handling, jquery-events

I wired the Change event handler for an ASP.NET radiobuttonlist like this in the `ready()` handler in jQuery like this:

```
$("#<%=rblYesNo.ClientID%>").change(MyFunction);
```

When I select one of the radio buttons, `MyFunction` doesn't get called. Why?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remember, a radio button list doesn't have a single identifier. The radio buttons are linked together by their NAME. If I recall, rblYesNo.ClientID will probably be just a div that wraps the radio buttons. Try:

```
$("#<%=rblYesNo.ClientID%> input").change(function(){

});
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of trouble. I wanted to use the attributes of the RadioButtonList. I put this in the document.ready function.

Answer (score 3):

IE has a problem with the 'change' event on radio buttons, try using click instead:

```
$("#<%=rblYesNo.ClientID%>").click(MyFunction);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#<%=rblYesNo.ClientID%> input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
                $(this).click(function() {
                alert((this).value);
            });
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

***$("#<%=rblYesNo.ClientID%> input").change(function(){
});***

and

***$("#<%=rblYesNo.ClientID%>").click(MyFunction);***

it may works in simple page. what if there is AjaxControlToolkit TabPanel in page?
it will not works. Because radio button list will be on other tab so it will find by the jquery and event cannot registered.